# Error parsing message with type 'tensorflow.SavedModel'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence, data-science

This is the error message i get-

```
Traceback:
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/app.py", line 131, in <module>
    label, perc = classifier(image, model_file)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 574, in wrapped_func
    return get_or_create_cached_value()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/legacy_caching/caching.py", line 558, in get_or_create_cached_value
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/app.py", line 52, in classifier
    model = tf.saved_model.load("my_model")
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 900, in load
    result = load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 913, in load_internal
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 60, in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info
    saved_model = _parse_saved_model(export_dir)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 108, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError(f"Cannot parse file {path_to_pb}: {str(e)}.")
```

I am trying to run a saved model (pb format) on Heroku. I am calling for loading a saved model using the snippet below-

```
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./my_model")

    # Create the array of the right shape to feed into the keras model
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 200, 200, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    image = img
    # image sizing
    size = (200, 200)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # turn the image into a numpy array
    image_array = np.asarray(image)
    # Normalize the image
    normalized_image_array = image_array.astype(np.float32) / 255

    # Load the image into the array
    data[0] = normalized_image_array

    # run the inference

    predict_dataset = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.array(normalized_image_array))

    # training=False is needed only if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    predictions = model(predict_dataset, training=False)
    prediction_percentage = predictions.numpy()[0][0]
    prediction = prediction_percentage.round()
```

Please note that the model is a tensorflow model saved in pb format and contains multiple files such as variables.data 00000 out of 00001 and saved_model.pb

Edit- I would like to point out that the model was saved on tensorflow version 2.7.0 using the save method

```
@staticmethod
    def model_saver(model_obj):
        try:
            model_obj.save("./FreshPrice/Output/my_model")
        except:
            print("Model not saved successfully!")
```

I am trying to run the model on heroku where I am using tensorflow-cpu (2.7.0) to run the loaded model. I used tf-cpu since it has lower size than tf.

Please advise on the error! any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you add how you saved the model? please include the version of TF used to save it. The reason is, the model might have been saved with TF v1, in which case you might need https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/saved_model/load

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez , I have edited the information. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: I think if it's SavedModel you should load it with  tf.saved_model.load instead of tf.keras.models.load_model

Comment: I tried both ways, still gives me the same error

Comment: Here is the relevant code path in TF repo: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/78ebd85a94f5a38bb0cc8a8f7a9291fad689334c/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py#L101 Seems like an issue with how the model was saved. Did anything go awry when you copied the saved model up to Heroku? If you do `ls  my_model` on the Heroku box is everything there (i.e., `assets`  `keras_metadata.pb`  `saved_model.pb`  `variables`)?

Comment: @joshwa yes, i get all the aforementioned listings on my_model

Comment: If you have save the model using `model.save('/my_model')` use `tf.keras.models.load_model('/my_model')` .  Otherwise Use To Save: `tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir)` and 
To Load: `model = tf.saved_model.load(path_to_dir)`. In this case you have saved the model with different format and loading in different format. For more information visit https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model. Thanks!